# javascript help, unable to decode

Tags: javascript

So i've been asked to rebuild a website, however I'm trying to figure out what the below javascript actually does, from what i've found online it's written very badly and probably why i can't figure it out.

it's mainly 'SPCost += (nBks

The website of the complete form is http://dynamic-stationery.com/online_order_form/

```
var setup = 110;  // film and screen
var perBk = 0.77;  // printing cost per book
var thresh = 200;
var minCost = 20;
var GST = 0.1;
var numCostPBk = nums ? 1.0 : 0.0;

var SPCost;
if (CC) {
  SPCost = nInks * (setup + nBks * (perBk + numCostPBk));
  SPCost += nBks < thresh ? minCost : nBks * minCost / thresh;
  SPCost *= 1 + GST;
  SPCost = Round(SPCost);
} else {
  SPCost = 0;
}
```

Comment: It's performing some math. Nothing bad about it. The variable names could be better but I digress. It's just doing some math. `+` for addition, `-` for subtraction, `*` for multiplication, etc.

Comment: it does.. math.. there's nothing wrong with it.. tell us what it's doing that you don't want it to do..

Comment: [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: Maybe you're confused by the [compound assignment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2xk8y0c(v=vs.94).aspx) operator? `a += 1` is the same as `a = a +1`.

Comment: @MikeC - my mistake.. missed htat..

Answer (score 0):

Could read it something like this

```
SPCost = Number of Inks * Setup Fee (110) + Number of Books * (perBk (0.77) +  numCostPBk (If numbers, 1.0 else 0.0)) 
The above will return a single number. 

SPCost += IF number of books is less than thresh (200) then minCost else Number of books * minCost (20) / thresh (200) 
SPCost += 1+ GST (0.1)

^^ Add these numbers to the first one

SPCost = round the combined totals.
```